# Spring Integration: Listening for exceptions on inbound-gateway

Tags: exception, integration, spring-integration, channel

I'm new to spring integration so I may misuse terms.
I've a ws:inbound-gateway listening to soap web service requests.

```
<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="myInGW"
                        request-channel="headersMapPopulationChannel"
                        reply-channel="ws-response-channel"
                        marshaller="marshaller"
                        unmarshaller="marshaller"/>
```

It sends incoming requests to headersMapPopulationChannel and it sends message to adapters(for converting from JAXB classes to domain) and splitter split it to validating, logging and persistence. After persistence I'm running business related things over request. I want to have exception control point over all of these, so that I can manage what to do in a case of exception. I put a throw exception statement in the business class on purpose. Exception is thrown but my channel doesn't seem to get it.
Configuration:

```
<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="myInGW"
                        request-channel="headersMapPopulationChannel"
                        reply-channel="ws-response-channel"
                        error-channel="ws-error-channel"
                        marshaller="marshaller"
                        unmarshaller="marshaller"/>

<int:channel id="ws-error-channel"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="ws-error-channel"
                       expression="@exceptionHandlerService.handleThrowable(payload)"/>
<bean id="exceptionHandlerService" class="pack.integration.service.ExceptionHandlerService"/>
```

Also I don't know whether controlling exception in my out-most channel is correct or not. Should I listen for exception wherever I forward the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to handle exceptions.

The exception will be wrapped in a `MessagingException` and sent to the `error-channel` as the payload of an `ErrorMessage`. The `MessagingException` has two properties `cause` (the original exception) and `failedMessage` (the message that caused the exception).

If you want to return a SOAP fault to the client, the error-channel flow must throw an exception.

If you are not seeing the `ErrorMessage` on the channel something else must be catching the exception.

I suggest you turn on debug logging and follow the messages through the system.

Comment: I've traced the flow as you said and I noticed an 'ignore-send-failures="true"' statement. Removing this made the error-channel to be able to catch exceptions. Thank for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I've also used a segment gateway to redirect all exceptions another message flow, and decide from there what to do with them.